# error in mingw, while scanning a string

Tags: c, mingw

I have just installed mingw. I am testing it . I just wrote a simple program. But it is giving error. What might the problem?

```
 int main()
    {
        char name[10];
        printf("Enter your name\t");
        scanf("%s", &name);
        printf("Hello %s",name);
        return 0;
    }
```

And the error was,

```
- format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]' [-
     Wformat]

- Line breakpoint: sorts.c [line: 16]
```

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
scanf("%s", &name);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

`&name` is a pointer to an array `10` of `char`, `name` is an array `10` of `char` converted to a pointer to `char` in the function call expression. `s` conversion specifier requires a pointer to `char` argument.

Comment: Still errors exist in project.Cannot open output file , test1.exe permission denied. After I fixed it. I did what u told before posting the question, but the problem of permission was occuring.

Comment: @ShreyasKale open a new question where you explain how you compile your program and what error you get.